# React Native getParam() function is undefined

Tags: react-native, navigation, expo

I am trying to pass variable from page to another using navigation method but when I try to read it as shown below I get the getParam() method is undefined. I am not using classes.

Here is the FirstPage from where I pass the variable

```
const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
setScanned(true);
//alert(`Bar code with type ${type} and data ${data} has been scanned!`);
splitted = data.split('=');
invitationFromURL=splitted[1];
navigation.navigate('HomeScreen',{text:invitationFromURL}); 


//console.log('Invite '+splitted[1]); 



};
```

Here is the Home page where I receive the variable

```
import { Image, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, Button,Alert } from 'react-native';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
//import { IconButton, Colors } from 'react-native-paper';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';


import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'


//import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';

import { MonoText } from '../components/StyledText';






export default function HomeScreen(props) {
const { navigation } = props

const text = navigation.getParams ('text','nothing sent');
```

The error I get
**
navigation.getParams is not a function. (In 'navigation.getParams('text', 'nothing sent')', 'navigation.getParams' is undefined) **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in react-navigation version 5 you should use **route** prop like that:

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation, route }) {
 const text = route.params?.text;

 return <View>...</View>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i thin'k you should upgrad your react-navigation v4 to v5 and use route.params?.someParam ?? 'defaultValue';

read documentation :=> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#no-more-getparam

Comment: What is the additional insight this answer provide in comparison to the existing and accepted answer? Note that anything which only provides a link is not considered an answer here.